# find specific period by two date fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

let's say I have datefield1 and datefield2, usually, datefield2 is 3 month ahead of datafield1. however, there's some case it's more than 3 months so I need to pull up only the date different is more than three months.

Example:

```
id | Datefield1 | Datefield2
1    08/15/2017    11/15/2017
2    05/10/2017    10/11/2017
3    06/01/2018   09/01/2017
```

the result should pull up only id 2.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at DATEDIFF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql

Comment: Asking *"How do I do this?"* should be accompanied with your own personal attempts to solve it, or at the least, a bit of research. As it stands this question is much too broad and comes across as a request for someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(MM,Datefield1,Datefield2) > 3
```

Can be used to find where the difference in months is more than 3.

Comment: Thanks. my other concern is how to update Datefiled2 = 3 if its more than 3.

Comment: What do you mean? Update it so that it has the integer 3 in it? Or change the month to be 3 months from Datefield1?

Comment: no that the date is three months different. exam datefield1 1/1/2017 datefield2 should be 3/1/2017.

Comment: Use DATEADD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql      DATEADD(MM,3,Datefield1) with an update statement using the WHERE clause with the DATEDIFF you have just learnt how to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use datediff to solver it:

```
select id
from t1
where DATEDIFF(month,Datefield1,Datefield2)>3
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't try it on SQL, but I think you could try with something like:

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE DATEDIFF(month,Datefield1,Datefield) > 3
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateDiff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql):

```
SELECT *
from table1
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, datefield1, datefield2)  > 3
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/35515/3)

This will give you id 2:

```
| id |           Datefield1 |           Datefield2 |
|----|----------------------|----------------------|
|  2 | 2017-05-10T00:00:00Z | 2017-10-11T00:00:00Z |
```

---

If you want to update, use `DATEADD`:

```
UPDATE t1
SET datefield2 = DateADD(MONTH, 3, datefield2)
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, datefield1, datefield2)  > 3;
```

Comment: My other question is how to update Datefiled2 = 3 if its more than 3.

Comment: @Messi `Datefiled2 ` is of data type datetime, you cannot updated it with integer?

Comment: i'm sorry i meant 3 months different.